# javascript valueOf() returns different integer values of same dates

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript. Here is my problem:

I'm comparing two dates to find whether they are equal. For that, I used `valueOf()` on two dates, but when I check same dates returning different values.

```
var today=new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0);//first date 
dbDate=new Date(inputArray[i].updatedAt.iso);
dbDate.setHours(0,0,0);//second date from my db
alert('compare');
             alert(today);
             alert(today.valueOf());
             alert(dbDate);
             alert(dbDate.valueOf());

              alert(today.valueOf()===dbDate.valueOf())
              if(today.valueOf()===dbDate.valueOf())//comparing
              {
                 alert('curr day if');
                 outArray.push(inputArray[i]);


              }
```

My system time is Mar 5 (I set time config to Malay Stadard Date). My retrieved date from database is also Mar 5, but both return different values and my comparison doesn't work as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There's probably a 1/1000 chance of them matching as Dates measure to milliseconds. [`.setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) has a 4th parameter available.

Comment: Can you do `date.toString`  and share its output in question?

Comment: You must display the relevant code require to recreate the bug or query.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski thanks after adding one more zero to function soved the problem...

Answer (score 2):

valueOf returns milliseconds, so you should set milliseconds in setHours too. Like that .setHours(0,0,0,**0**)